# NodeJS, ParseServer, kue-scheduler Query.every

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-server, kue

I'm using ParseServer(`v2.2.16`) and kue-sheduler(`v0.6.0`), my `Query.every` looks like: `Queue.every('0 12 * * *', job);`, what I expect is that the cron format will initiate the `job` every day at 12pm, I've tried so many formats but nothing works, after an hour or so the task initiates, maybe there is another format I should try?, is my format wrong?, is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [kue-scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue-scheduler) using [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) that uses following format

- Seconds: 0-59
- Minutes: 0-59
- Hours: 0-23
- Day of Month: 1-31
- Months: 0-11
- Day of Week: 0-6

that mean you cron format would be

```
Queue.every('00 00 12 * * *', job);
```

**References:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue-scheduler & https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Comment: Thanks it's working, well explained + a reference! :)